# Live AdMob ads are not displayed in test build, although the test ads works (no fresh account)

Tags: android, admob, ads

Live (functional) AdMob Ads not showing, test ads do.

I have a workıng AdMob ID that I try to reflect in v2 of my app. The Admob Account is up and running from a few months now, displaying ads and video in my live store app.
However, my new code has test ads implemented and they work as intended, but when I put the live ads codes (the same ones from AdMob that are currently running on the live app), no ads are shown in the test build on my devices.

Ads should be visible in my logic. What am I missing here? Since a) the code is ok; b) live ads on live app show; c) same ads ids as live app do not  show in debug.

Comment: are you using the release build on your device or r u building direct from android studio? live ads do not show in debug.

Comment: @soldforapp Running directly from Android Studio. Is this the issue? I will make a release .apk and see, thank you.

Comment: yes, thats why. if you are using live ads, you need to run them off release.

Comment: @soldforapp, I've installed a realease  apk. Indeed, video  rewards are available, now, your solution was on point. However, banners and interstitial are not. Any idea why?

Comment: could take time to update in their system. but not too sure.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by @soldforapp comment.

> are you using the release build on your device or r u building direct from android studio? live ads do not show in debug. if you are using live ads, you need to run them off release.

Ads are visible in release version.